# Calling a delegate in C# dll

Tags: c#, multithreading, dll

I'm working, for the first time, on a C# DLL. The DLL methods will be called by a C# application. The UI will be in the C# application. Up to now it's pretty basic.

But the work in the DLL has to be done in a thread belonging to the DLL. The work in the DLL can’t be executed in the UI thread context. So the DLL methods calls will be asynchronous and that's fine.

So basically the idea would be:

- The application includes the DLL in its project.
- The DLL defines various delegates.
- The application "subscribes" to these delegates.
- The UI thread calls a DLL method.
- The DLL receives the method call.
- There is a context switch to the DLL thread (to actually do the work associated with the method call).
- The UI thread continues its execution. The UI thread is not blocked and it doesn't wait.
- The DLL thread does some work.
- The DLL thread calls a delegate to notify the UI thread of the result.

How should the UI thread post a message to the DLL thread? Is there a straightforward way to do this?

What happens when the DLL thread calls the delegate? Is the delegate code executed in the DLL thread context or in the UI thread context?

It seems like the code will be executed in the DLL thread context. If it is the case, how can the delegate code be executed in the UI thread context?

Thanks for the help!

==================

EDIT: The DDL thread must stay alive as long as the application is alive. The DLL thread will also receive events from the network and then notify the UI thread.

In fact, the DLL needs to be a SDK to make VOIP calls. So anyone ready to code the UI could use our SDK.

A typical (simplified) scenario would be:

- At the application starts, the UI calls the DLL.Start(). This creates a thread within the DLL and make sure the DLL is ready to make and receive calls.
- The user dials a telephone number.
- The UI thread calls the MakeCall() method from the DLL.
- In the DLL, there is context switch to the DLL thread in order to start the new call. All the work for starting the call is made in the DLL thread.
- The UI thread is not blocked or doesn’t wait.
- At one point, the call is established.
- The DLL thread notifies the UI by calling a delegate method.

Comment: What does the DLL actually do? Does it function as some kind of lib? Because then you can ofcourse code delegate events.

Comment: @KevinKal Basically, the dll will start a voip call. So the application asks the dll to start a call. Once the call is started the dll notifies the application by calling a delegate. But it's very important that the actual delegate code is executed in the UI thread. This is where it's not clear for me.

Comment: And you 'include' the dll in your project? Just create a delegate event in the DLL. Which you set in the C# project.

Comment: If nothing works, you can always check out NamedPipes

Comment: Yes I include the dll in my project. Yes I will create a delegate event in the DLL which will be set in the C# project. When the delegate code is executed, do you know if it's executed in the context of the DLL thread? Or somehow the context switched to the UI thread?

Comment: That's something I actually don't know. You should find out. But you can make everything synced, so it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "synced"? Can you explain more?

Comment: @ccaron: calling a delegate will not mean automatic context switching between threads. You can confirm this in the debugger: just open up your threads view. Also remember to set the background threads ids so that you can better tell what's going on. So basically - don't worry.

Answer (score 1):

```
Task workerTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    // call your dll and do some long process
});

Task uiTask = workerTask.ContinueWith((x) =>
{
    // update your ui (textBox.Text = x.Value;)
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

[TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.fromcurrentsynchronizationcontext(v=vs.110).aspx) - captures current (UI) synchronization context, so update will happen on ui context

Answer (score 0):

> Does the application need to have two threads, one thread to
>   communicate with the DLL and another thread for the UI?

Your application only requires one GUI thread and one additional thread for your DLL context. No further threads are required to synchronize them.

> It seems like the code will be executed in the DLL thread context. If
>   it is the case, how can the delegate code be executed in the UI thread
>   context?

If you try to call WinForm methods from another thread than the GUI thread in which their corresponding object was created, you will get an `InvalidOperationException` as this case is checked by WinForms. A simple approach is to check if you need to change your thread context inside the eventhandler like this:

Handled Event:

```
public event Action<string> OnCallWithString;
```

Eventhandler:

```
void Form_OnCallWithString(string obj)
{
    if (InvokeRequired) Invoke(new Action<string>(Form_OnCallWithString), obj);
    else
    { 
        //normal eventhandler logic here
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should look up `BackgroundWorker` in C#, this is designed to do exactly what you want - execute something on the background thread and pass the result back to the UI thread.

This would be much better than trying to craft your own threading and marshalling in the DLL.  Let that just be a library of functions and let the caller worry about which threads it wants to use.

Comment: Do you mean having a BackgroundWorker in the DLL? Can a BackgroundWorker "live" until the application is terminated? It needs to be the same single thread (or maybe single BackgroundWorker) that is started once during the application execution.